# Create a popup window to confirm quitting a tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have an "exit" button that when you press it, a new window will pop up asking if you're sure you want to exit. I've only just started using `tkinter` so I am not sure how to proceed: so far my app overlays my exit screen on top of my title screen and makes a seemingly random new blank windows.

Heres my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

##_______________EXIT_______________
def closeyes():
    exit()

def closeno():
    exitsure.destroy()

def close_window():
    exitsure = tk.Tk()

    areyousure = tk.Label(text="Are you sure you want to exit?")
    areyousure.grid(column=0, row=0)

    ExitYes = tk.Button(text="Yes", command = closeyes)
    ExitYes.grid(column=0, row=2)

    ExitNo = tk.Button(text="No", command = closeno)
    ExitNo.grid(column=2, row=2)
    exitsure.mainloop()

#_______________START_______________
start = tk.Tk()

start.title("THE MEGA POP QUIZ")

#Start Title
start_title = tk.Label(text="Welcome to THE MEGA POP QUIZ")
start_title.grid(column=0, row=1)

#Begin button
def BEGIN():
    start.destroy()

Button1 = tk.Button(text="BEGIN", command = BEGIN)
Button1.grid(column=0, row=2)

#Exit
ExitButton = tk.Button(text="EXIT", width = 14, command = close_window)
ExitButton.grid(column=0, row=0)

start.mainloop()
```

I thought exitsure = tk.Tk would make a new window, and then if they pressed the no button, it would only destroy exitsure, but if they chose the yes button, it would exit everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal, **reusable** example where pressing the `QUIT` button on the main App, launches a popup window asking you to confirm.

Upon confirmation, the App is closed; if not, the popup closes and the App remains active.

This `PopUpConfirmQuit` class can be reused as it is with other tkinter apps; it only requires that the quit button of the main app launches it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class PopUpConfirmQuit(tk.Toplevel):
    """A TopLevel popup that asks for confirmation that the user wants to quit.
                                                                              .
    Upon confirmation, the App is destroyed.
    If not, the popup closes and no further action is taken
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Are you sure you want to quit").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='confirm', command=master.destroy, fg='red').pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text='Nooooo!', command=self.destroy).pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)


class App(tk.Tk):
    """a minimal example App containing only a QUIT button, that launches
    a confirmation popup window
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.quitbutton = tk.Button(self, text='QUIT', command=lambda: PopUpConfirmQuit(self))
        self.quitbutton.pack()
        self.mainloop()


App()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

# this is the code i designed and is working fine with me and i hope will resolve your issue as well....

basically if u press yes then use quit command and in no button destroy the same message window...

better not to create new functions for small small tasks

```
#  **************** quit code ***********
from tkinter import *

def quit_msg():
    qw=Tk()
    frame1 = Frame(qw, highlightbackground="green", highlightcolor="green",highlightthickness=1, bd=0)
    frame1.pack()
    qw.overrideredirect(1)
    qw.geometry("200x70+650+400")
    lbl = Label(frame1, text="are you sure you want to quit")
    lbl.pack()
    yes_btn = Button(frame1, text="Yes", bg="light blue", fg="red",command=quit, width=10)
    yes_btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10 , side=LEFT)
    no_btn = Button(frame1, text="No", bg="light blue", fg="red",command=qw.destroy, width=10)
    no_btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)
    qw.mainloop()
```

[image]

```
#  ***************  main window ***********

mw=Tk()
mw.overrideredirect(1)
mw.geometry("300x100")
btn=Button(mw, text="click to close", bg="red", fg="white", width=10, command=quit_msg).pack(pady=30)
mw.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright I just fixed it myself using tk.Toplevel(), thanks guys, here the fixed code:

import random
import tkinter as tk

```
##_____________EXIT_______________

def EXIT():
    exitsure = tk.Toplevel()

    areyousure = tk.Label(exitsure, text="Are you sure you want to exit?")
    areyousure.grid(column=0, row=0)

    ExitYes = tk.Button(exitsure, text="Yes", command=quit)
    ExitYes.grid(column=0, row=2)

    NoYes = tk.Button(exitsure, text="No", command=exitsure.destroy)
    NoYes.grid(column=2, row=2)

#_____________START_______________
start = tk.Tk()

start.title("THE MEGA POP QUIZ")

#Start Title
start_title = tk.Label(text="Welcome to THE MEGA POP QUIZ")
start_title.grid(column=0, row=1)

#Begin button
def BEGIN():
    start.destroy()

Button1 = tk.Button(text="BEGIN", command = BEGIN)
Button1.grid(column=0, row=2)

#Exit
ExitButton = tk.Button(text="EXIT", command = EXIT)
ExitButton.grid(column=0, row=0)

start.mainloop()
```